# Delete the item once it is added

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-handlers

I want to perform some Action once the item is added. I have a Custom List that reacts on Item Creation.

If, at this level, i want to Delete the item immediately once it is added, how could I do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sharepoint designer to create a list workflow for the list.

You can use conditions to determine if the item should be deleted.

Then you can delete the current item.

Answer (score 2):

As C.Marius mentions, if you are able to add custom code, go for a Event Handler.

To point you in the right direction, check this example out;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx

But would it not be better to prevent users to add the listitem in the first place?

Anyway, the most simple approach i can think off:

```
Public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    properties.ListItem.Delete();
    properties.Cancel = true;
}
```

And dont forget to scope the Event Handler to the specific list in the Elements.xml, just change

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
```

to this

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/someListName">
```

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the intended approach:

1. By code - you always have Event Handlers (OnItemAdding  -
   synchronous, which can be cancelled if a certain condition is not
   met or  OnItemAdded - asynchronous - if you wish to perform some
   stuff prior to deleting it, that triggers after the actual item has
   been created). Great advantage of a handler is that you could tie
   that into a content type, certain list type - which increase
   reusability
2. As Russell already mentioned, more declarative, for special cases, or if you are rather targeting Content types - a Reusable workflow.